# Echoing custom messages over SSH error

Tags: machines, network, msg, multiple, ssh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node running on an embedded platform publishing a custom message (just a `float32[]`). I have a ros master running on a different machine, and both `ROS_MASTER_URI`s and `ROS_IP`s are set correctly. On the master machine, if I run `rostopic echo <topic>`, I get:

```
 ERROR: Cannot load message class for [<package>/<msg>]. Are your messages built?
```

If I ssh into the embedded platform and run a `rostopic echo <topic>`, I get the data printed out.

I think I understand why it's not working - I haven't sourced the workspace on the embedded platform from the master - but I don't know the solution to this problem, since I want to be able to run nodes on multiple platforms, including the master.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223974/echoing-custom-messages-over-ssh-error/) by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should source or install the custom message on the master machine.   If it was std_msgs, it would be installed on both but a custom message would not be found on the master machine as the warning says.

---

Originally posted by [tonybaltovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/3462/tonybaltovski/) with karma: 2549 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djsw](https://answers.ros.org/users/25492/djsw/) on 2016-01-13**:
I made a package specifically to hold the message I was using, then copied it across to my master and built the package (i.e., "install the custom message on the master machine"). This fixed the problem.